# Having Problems Adding core plot to OS X project

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6, core-plot

Hello I have developed for couple months my OS X project that includes a `corePlot` frameWork in debug everything works fine , the project compiles and runs flawlessly ,
however when I did **product->archive->export as mac app** I have received the .app file as needed but when I tried to run it the application is just never opens :-O

(I can see in doc that it tries to open and dies immediately).

I tried to discover what is wrong there , so I opened the .app context file and found an exe that said to me that it can't find the `corePlot` framework.

**dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot**

It is sad i tried to re add the `corePlot` to my project several times, but the app doesn't find it :(

(I have done the `corePlot` integration according to a tutorial.

After playing with it , I found that I had to create and copy `Frameworks` folder inside the .app's context . However I have done it manually , how do I make Xcode to manage it for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app target in the Xcode project, make sure you have a "Copy Frameworks" build phase and that Core Plot is one of the frameworks to copy.